# Which is better for faster browsing speed? download different images from different site/one site for a webpage's images [HTML/PHP]

Tags: javascript, php, html

[ I am not sure **StackOverflow** is the right place to ask the question because it is slightly related to programming ]

Suppose my web page needs 2 images to display . Now I have two options before displaying them into my **HTML**/**PHP**:

1) Upload all of them in one site 
( Is it faster ? because everything is in one place)

2) Upload them in different site
( Is there any pipeline effect ? )

for example : I have two images : **a.jpg** and **b.jpg** to display . Now Which upload is better for browsing speed to my webpage?

Either :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<img src=website1.com/a.jpg>
<img src=website2.com/b.jpg>
</body>
</html>
```

Or :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<img src=website1.com/a.jpg>
<img src=website1.com/b.jpg>
</body>
</html>
```

Or there is no effect ?

Comment: Run a benchmark and see.

Comment: how to run benchmark?

Comment: It doesn't matter. Not directly. 2 images will still be downloaded in the same fashion in either case. If one host is faster to download from, then _that_ will make a difference.

Comment: A general answer is _obviously_ not possible. There are many, many aspects to consider, none of those known.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With 2 images, it wouldn't really matter.

If you had 2 000 images in the same pages, it would be interesting to split them in different servers. But this would mean you have a **really big problem elsewhere**.

In fact, this kind of question is more server-side related. You want to make that kind of optimization ? Use a CDN:

- It will handle the load
- Optimize caching
- Use localized servers
- Some other features